# Show images from the internet in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I want that this 200 Pictures are in every row of the ListView.
Where I have to copy this code which collect the pictures from the internet in my CustomAdapter?

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= 200; i++){
    final int ii = i;
    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(CustomListView.this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //linearLayout.addView(imageView,lp);

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            final Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromURL("http://ruthe.de/cartoons/strip_"+getPictureName(ii)+".jpg");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(bm !=null){
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    }
                    else {
                        //linearLayout.removeView(imageView);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };thread.start ();
}
```

This is my CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter   implements View.OnClickListener {
    /*********** Declare Used Variables *********/
    private Activity activity;
private ArrayList data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public Resources res;
ListModel tempValues=null;
int i=0;

/*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d,Resources resLocal) {

    /********** Take passed values **********/
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    res = resLocal;

    /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () ***********/
    inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

/******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
public int getCount() {
    if(data.size()<=0)
        return 1;
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

/********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView text;
    public TextView text1;
    public TextView textWide;
    public ImageView image;
}

/****** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row *****/
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){
        /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null);

        /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag( holder );
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    if(data.size()<=0)
    {
        holder.text.setText("No Data");
    }
    else
    {
        /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
        tempValues=null;
        tempValues = ( ListModel ) data.get(position);
        /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/
        holder.text.setText(tempValues.getCompanyName());
        holder.text1.setText( tempValues.getUrl() );
        holder.image.setImageResource(
                res.getIdentifier(
                        "com.androidexample.customlistview:drawable/"+tempValues.getImage(),null,null));
        /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row *******/
        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener( position ));
    }
    return vi;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.v("CustomAdapter", "=====Row button clicked=====");
}

/********* Called when Item click in ListView ************/
private class OnItemClickListener  implements View.OnClickListener{
    private int mPosition;

    OnItemClickListener(int position){
        mPosition = position;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {


        CustomListView sct = (CustomListView)activity;

        /****  Call  onItemClick Method inside CustomListViewAndroidExample Class ( See Below )****/

        sct.onItemClick(mPosition);
    }
}


//My own code
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {URL url = new URL(src);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
} //PICTURE BITMAP

public String getPictureName (int i){
    String in = ""+i+"";
    if(in.length() == 1){
        return "000"+in;
    }
    else if(in.length() == 2){
        return "00"+in;
    }
    else if(in.length() == 3){
        return "0"+in;
    }
    else{
        return in;
    }
}
```

I searched on the whole internet but I dont found something which explains how to get pictures from the Internet into every row of a ListView...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PICASsO** allows for hassle-free image loading in your application—often in one line of code!
for the library check this link http://square.github.io/picasso/
 and at the bottom of page you can download jar file and just paste it in the **libs** folder

```
Picasso.with(context).load("YOUR IMAGE URL").into(imageView);
```

int your getView method

do it like

```
holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
```

and then

```
Picasso.with(context).load("YOUR IMAGE URL").into(holder.image);
```

Comment: You can also try Universal Image Loader - https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Thanks. I used the Universal Image Loader

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Picasso library. It makes it extremely easy.
http://square.github.io/picasso/

To use it, simply find your ImageView with the standard findViewById, then use the following code:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("www.google.com/images/1").into(imageView);
```

Simply input the URL and the ImageView, and Picasso will async load the image and put it in the imageview.

Im currently using it to show a list of over 400 images in a listview, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the thread you can use the bitmap object inside the adapter itself and initialize the image view with the bitmap object, using position integer instead of (ii).

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have found a workaround for my app: i have create a class type:

```
public class myClass {
....
...
private Bitmap imguser;
```

..  and into costructor i have added objects for async task like Future and i send image name
received from server side....

```
public myClass(..., ..,..,String userid, ...){

    Future<Bitmap> futureimguser;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); 

    getImgFromSite getimguserfromsite = new getImgFromSite(userid,"imguser");

    futureico = executor.submit(geticofromsite);
    futureimguser = executor.submit(getimguserfromsite)


        .......


    this.imguser = futureimguser.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        this.icopoi = futureico.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    executor.shutdown();
```

next i have a method like below which loads images from my site.

```
private final class getImgFromSite implements  Callable<Bitmap>  {
    String imgsrc = new String();
    String imgtipo = new String();
    public getImgFromSite(String srcimg,String imgtipo) {

        this.imgsrc = srcimg;
        this.imgtipo = imgtipo;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap call() throws Exception {
        String imgpath;
        if(imgtipo.compareTo("imguser") == 0){
            imgpath = "http://mysite/assets/imgcomics/"+imgsrc+".jpg";
        }
        else{
            imgpath = "http://mysite/"+imgsrc;

        }

        Bitmap myBitmap; 
        URL url = new URL(imgpath);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            myBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
           return myBitmap;

    }

}
```

Hope that i have help you!